# Google App Engine ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, python-2.7

I've come to run my app in development locally this morning, in the Google App Engine Launcher for Windows.  Up until yesterday this has been working fine, and the code hasn't been changed since then.

Now, when I try to run the app on localhost I get the yellow warning sign in the Launcher and the log shows the following;

```
2012-08-02 08:37:54 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\preston\\My Documents\\Google Drive\\Development\\Instance']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 157, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 41, in <module>
    import mimetypes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
2012-08-02 08:37:55 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I've only ever had Python 2.7 installed on this machine, nothing has ever attempted to use python26.dll before as far as I know...

Also, I've checked the Launcher for updates, nothing found.  Has anybody experienced this before?  The most baffling thing to me is that it's changed behaviour since yesterday...

Comment: Was any other software installed recently? Something added a python26.dll to your machine, at the very least.

Comment: import _socket <-- is that the underlying C library?  Just reinstall the app engine?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Remember I actually installed Google Drive, I'll try turning that off.

Comment: @NIleshSharma: That's a completely different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solved:  As per commenter's hints, I tried closing all applications running which had been installed since the last successful run.  This amounted to only one; Google Drive.  Stopping that process allows the App Engine Launcher to run the app just fine, so the conflict's coming from two Google apps!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Very surprising that the Google Drive process (which indeed does use Python 2.6) is interfering with the App Engine SDK. But then again, I never use Windows, and perhaps there is a linking error in either build that causes Windows to use the wrong .dll for one or the other when *a* python .dll has been loaded.

Comment: I was trying to work it out too, and I think that must be it - if there's a Python dll already linked somewhere, we seem to just try and use that one!